# How to create a custom form field type in a module?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

Im useing joomla 2.5, and I want to create a custom form field type `that stored in the same module.`

In the XML:

```
 <fieldset  name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_royalslider/fields"></fields>
      <fieldset name="basic">
           <field name="title" type="City" label="anythging" description=""   />
      </fieldset>
 </fields>
```

In the file `/modules/mod_royalslider/fields/city.php`

```
<?php
// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldCity extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'City';

    // getLabel() left out

    public function getInput() {
            return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
                   '<option value="1" >New York</option>'.
                   '<option value="2" >Chicago</option>'.
                   '<option value="3" >San Francisco</option>'.
                   '</select>';
    }
}
```

for now it show me error, when ever i remove 
 `<fieldset  name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_royalslider/fields"></fields>`

the error gone and the field disply as a text field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot to specify **models** in the `addfieldpath`

```
<fields name="params">
   <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_royalslider/models/fields">

       <field name="title" type="City" label="anythging" description=""   />

   </fieldset>
</fields>
```

Just put the fields folder inside the models folder and put the path like above.

Comment: Not worked. However, it's a path at the end I moved the php file to the same path.

Do any body has an open source files!

Answer (score 1):

You just do it using the code you gave, easy:

```
 <fields>
      <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_royalslider/fields">
           <field name="title" type="City" label="anythging" description=""   />
      </fieldset>
 </fields>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addfieldpath` within fields as like ::

```
<fields name="params" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_royalslider/models/fields" >

       <fieldset name="basic">

         <field name="title" type="City" label="anything" description="" />

       </fieldset>
 </fields>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try using this code. this work in mine

```
<fieldset addfieldpath="/modules/mod_royalslider/models/fields" name="basic">

   <field name="title" type="City" label="anything" description=""  />

</fieldset>
```