# How to style Joomla 3.x module backend view?

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have my module up and running and now I'd like to make module administering a bit more eye-friendly, as there's a huge textbox by default which takes up too much room on the screen. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a custom form field.

Comment: Go with custom field. You can refer 
https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197236/how-to-create-a-custom-form-field-type-in-a-module